# PHP mysql successfully upload file to one table but not the other

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file to a database(using php and mysql). I can successfully upload the file and save its path in one table, but when I try to upload the file to another table, I got an error that says:move_uploaded_file: failed to open stream. However, if I create another database, I can successfully upload the file again. Can I only upload the file to one table but not multiple tables in the same database? Because of the design of my project, I want to upload files to 2 tables in the same database, can someone tell me how to do it? 
This is the code that can successfully upload the file, the name of the table is photos:

```
    <?php
    include('config.php');
        $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
        $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);                   
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos/" $_FILES["image"]["name"]);    
        $location="photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
        $description=$_POST['description'];
        $save=mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos (location, description) VALUES ('$location','$description')");


        }
    ?>
```

I try to upload file to another table by the following code.i simply changed photos to photos2, photos2 is the name of another table

```
<?php
    include('config.php');
        $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
        $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);                   
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos2/" $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

    $location="photos2/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $description=$_POST['description'];
    $save=mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos2 (location, description) VALUES ('$location','$description')");                   
 }
?>
```

I got the following error: 
Warning: move_uploaded_file: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\XAMPP\tmp\php1793.tmp' to 'photos2/1.png'

Also, I know that mysql is deprecated and I need to change it to mysqli, I will do that in the future, right now I just want to know how to upload file to 2 tables in the same database.

Update: I think the way I phrased my question cause my unnecessary confusion. This is what I meant by "upload to 2 tables": I have two pages on my website, let's call them page A and Page B, users can upload photos on Page A and Page B, photos uploaded from page A can only be seen on Page A, likewise, photos uploaded from Page B can only be seen on Page B. Therefore, it makes sense to create 2 separate tables to store photos. If they're stored in the same table, then on each page, when I ("SELECT*FROM photos"), the query will search through all the photos that are uploaded from another page, which is unnecessary. I don't need to upload the same photo to two different tables at the same time.

Comment: What you're attempting is certainly possible, though the error message you are receiving is due to a missing **folder** called photos2. Are you attempting to upload to the same folder, and simply change the table? If so, change the `photos2` in `move_uploaded_file` and `$location` to simply `photos`. Otherwise, create the `photos2` folder :)

Comment: No. It's because the file he's trying to move FROM doesn't exist anymore, since he already moved it.

Comment: *"right now I just want to know how to upload file to 2 tables in the same database"* - What; at the same time or in different operations? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this.

Comment: I updated my question to answer some of the comments.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `move_uploaded_file`, the file is MOVED. Hence, it won't exist when you try to run the second bit of code... This is fairly obvious. Try this:

```
<?php
include('config.php');
    $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);                   
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos/" $_FILES["image"]["name"]);    
    copy('photos/'.$_FILES['image']['name'],'photos2/'.$_FILES['image']['name']);
    $location="photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $description=$_POST['description'];
    $save=mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos (location, description) VALUES ('$location','$description')");
    $save=mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos2 (location, description) VALUES ('$location','$description')");
    }
?>
```